# How can I have TikZ automata accepting nodes be the same size as nonaccepting nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to use the TikZ automata library to draw finite automata where the size of the state nodes remains the same regardless of whether the state is accepting or not.

Here's a MWE demonstrating the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\tikzstyle{accepting}=[double distance=2pt, outer sep=1pt+\pgflinewidth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines, step=.5cm] (0, 0) grid (4,2);
  \node[state] (q0) at (1,1) {};
  \node[state, accepting] (q1) at (3,1) {};
  \draw (q0) edge [bend left=15, ->] (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two node automata]

You can see that the accepting node is larger than the nonaccepting node.

I believe I understand *why* this is happening: `double distance` turns on `double` which causes TikZ to draw two circles with different colors and different widths, first in black with width `2pt+2\pgflinewidth` and then in white with width `2pt`. This results in the appearance of a double line.

Is there a way that I can modify the style set by `accepting` such that it reduces the size of the node (or maybe `inner sep`) appropriately such that the node size doesn't change? Alternatively, can I cause `accepting` to simply draw a second circle centered on the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fighting this for days, I found a solution shortly after posting the question, of course.

My solution uses the `calc` library and `path picture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, calc}

\tikzstyle{accepting}=[path picture={%
  \draw let 
    \p1 = (path picture bounding box.east),
    \p2 = (path picture bounding box.center)
    in
      (\p2) circle (\x1 - \x2 - 2pt);
  }]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines, step=.5cm] (0, 0) grid (4,2);
  \node[state] (q0) at (1,1) {};
  \node[state, accepting] (q1) at (3,1) {};
  \draw (q0) edge [bend left=15, ->] (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]