# how to draw automata with 4 states

Tags: draw

i am a student and i am trying to solve this problem

> draw an automata with 4 states accepting this `(a,ab,ba)*`

i have tried many times drawing it but unfortunately i am unable to solve it.
i don't know how much i have to keep writing in order for this to accept my question
can anyone show me how to draw it please ?
i appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: Hi berobero and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: welcome to tex.se. see *Automata Drawing Library* in tikz & pgf manual, page 513. by the way, this site is not intended for solving students homework ...

Comment: Funny thing: Two questions prior to yours is this: [How can I have TikZ automata accepting nodes be the same size as nonaccepting nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411770)

Comment: By `(a,ab,ba)*`, you mean `(a+ab+ba)*`, right?

Comment: yes it is the same (a,ab,ba)* and (a+ab+ba)* ....... how to draw it ?

Comment: help please anyone ? how to draw this (a+ab+ba)*